# Webpart properties getting empty after IIS Reset

Tags: 2007, development, web-part, user-controls

I created a custom visual user control webpart property for my SharePoint webpart. The property has a textbox which is getting empty after an IIS reset. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue please.
Sometimes it resets itself without IIS reset as well not 100% sure though.

**EDIT**

My webpart class

```
public class MyVisualBoard : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
{
    public const string webPartName = "MyVisualBoard";
    private string _ascxPath;

    public MyVisualBoard()
    {
        _ascxPath = @"~/_ControlTemplates/MyVisualBoard/MyVisualBoardUserControl.ascx";
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls(); //Always child controls under base childcontrols

        try
        {
            Control userControl = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
            Controls.Add(userControl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogErrorMessage(ex, webPartName, Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogErrorMessage(ex, webPartName, Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            ShowErrorMessage(String.Empty);
            return;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Script manager need to be added for the update panel to work
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page) == null)
        {
            ScriptManager sMgr = new ScriptManager();
            Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, sMgr);
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    public static decimal MyCustomProperty;
    [SPWebCategoryName("My Custom Property")]
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
    [WebDisplayName("My Custom Property")]
    [WebBrowsable(true)]
    public decimal _MyCustomProperty
    {
        get { return MyCustomProperty; }
        set { MyCustomProperty = value; }
    }
```

//more custom properties are just like it (like 7 of them)

User control class looks like this,

```
using MyVisualBoard.WebParts.MyVisualBoard;

namespace MyVisualBoard.Webparts.MyVisualBoard
{
    public partial class MyVisualBoardUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private const string webPartName = "MyVisualBoard";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MyCustomProperty.Text = MyVisualBoard.MyCustomProperty;
        }

        //Some  other methods here as well
```

Comment: how about the code that you use to Persist the properties?. Can you paste the code here?

Comment: @FalakMahmood I added some code, and whats your skype bro, never able to get you on twitter you know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeToThine,

A similar question was asked,

@Ryan has answered the question, credits to him!
[Sharepoint Webpart custom properties get default values on server reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697314/sharepoint-webpart-custom-properties-get-default-values-on-server-reboot)

Similar question on StackExchange:
[Sharepoint Webpart custom properties get default values on server reboot](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/sharepoint-webpart-custom-properties-get-default-values-on-server-reboot)

So instead of using static variable, use non-static!

And you can access the property as described in below article [It is for SP2010 but it should work]:
[Custom Properties in SharePoint 2010 Visual Web Parts](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2011/04/custom-properties-in-sharepoint-2010_7158.html)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you programmed your webpart correctly the properties for the webpart are stored in the content database, so it shouldn't be an issue resetting the IIS or whatever.

Basically there is a lot of information on the internet. 
For example [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

If you want more info just search for custom webpart properties or persisting webpart properties.

Happy coding!

Comment: I think you didn't read my question properly, I am talking about User Control (Visual Webparts in 2007) not  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart ones , but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This should point you into the right direction :)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29285/Simple-WebPart-To-Load-UserControl

hope it help :)